# org-roam buffer default toggled on

Tags: org-mode

I'm still new to org-mode and am trying to set up this [org-roam](https://github.com/jethrokuan/org-roam) package. My goal is to have the buffer containing backlinks automatically show whenever I open a file, but can't seem to get that configuration set up. Here's my `.init` file for `org-roam`:

```lisp
(use-package org-roam
      :hook 
      (after-init . org-roam-mode)
      :custom
      (org-roam-directory "~/org/")
      :bind (:map org-roam-mode-map
              (("C-c n l" . org-rOam)
               ("C-c n f" . org-roam-find-file)
               ("C-c n b" . org-roam-switch-to-buffer)
               ("C-c n g" . org-roam-graph-show))
              :map org-mode-map
              (("C-c n i" . org-roam-insert))))

(setq org-roam-link-title-format "R:%s")
(setq org-roam-completion-system 'ivy)
```

Comment: When you open *any* file? Or specifically `org-roam` files?

Comment: Have you tried asking at the org-roam github site?